# Passing a model to view and losing property values on HttpPost

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im a newbie to MVC and I'm guessing this question reflects it.

I have 2 ActionResults - Register - one on `HttpGet` the other on `HttpPost`. On the `HttpGet`, I create an instance of the model, set the firm property depending on the query string value and pass the model to the view. So far, so good.

When the `HttpPost` happens, the firm property is set to null. As if nothing was set. What am I doing wrong?

**Register HTTPGet**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register(Guid Firm)
{
    InnuendoContext DB = new InnuendoContext();

     RegisterModel RM = new RegisterModel();
     RM.Firm = (from F in DB.Firms
         where F.FirmId == Firm
         select F).FirstOrDefault();

    return View(RM);
}
```

**Register HTTPPost**

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register( RegisterModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Attempt to register the user
        try
        {
            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, propertyValues: new 
            { 
                Name = model.Name,
                Surname = model.Surname,
                Firm_FirmID = model.Firm 
            });
            WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
        { 
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model Innuendo.Models.RegisterModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
    <h2>Create a new account.</h2>
</hgroup>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

<fieldset>
    <legend>Registration Form</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Surname)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Surname)
        </li>

        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
        </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
</fieldset>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**Model**

```
namespace Innuendo.Models
{
    [Table("Firms")]
    public class FirmModel
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid FirmId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Firm Name")]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(250)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual AddressModel Address { get; set; }

        [StringLength(250)]
        public string LogoPath { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a property in `RegisterModel` to hold firm ID and pass this id to your view and post back ID with a hidden input.

```
public RegisterModel
{
    // other codes
    public Guid FirmID {get;set;}
}
```

In you get action:

```
public ActionResult Register(Guid Firm)
{
    // other codes
    // also don't fetch firm object if you don't want to show firm data to user
    RM.FirmID=Firm;
    View(RM);
}
```

In your view add a hidden field inside of your form element:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.FirmID);
```

And in post back action you could use id to fetch your object

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    // other codes

    // your firm id is here you could do whatever you want
    var firmID=model.FirmID;

}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. I didnt know that I had to add a hidden field, thought MVC would know about them. Much obliged all.

Comment: What if i got a more complicated property types than primitive ones? Do i need to create a hidden input for each one of it's properties?

Answer (score 0):

There is no input field to set your firm property in the register view so it is returned as null

Comment: What if I dont want to display those fields and Im just passing those fields because I want to do something with them on HTTPPost? Should I Check the querystring in the HTTPPost and do the logic im doing in the HTTPGet there?

Comment: @user1203996, in that case you use Hidden fields: instead of TextBoxFor( ) you need to use HiddenFor( ). In MVC everything you want to pass to the server via POST or GET, need to be in inputs: textboxes, textareas, hiddens, selects, etc.

Comment: Just use HiddenFor() like Romias ans gardarvalur said